# List Sorting with specific text and order based on user choice

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to sort the following list based on prop1 first and then based on the prop2 value of my choice. For example I want to sort the list in ascending order using prop1 and then prop2 which contains the value "project", then prop2 which contains the value "application" and then then prop2 which contains the value "core"

```
IList<Test> tests = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="project235"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="core222"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="application33331"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="project"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="application21"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="core1"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name1", prop2="application"},

            new Test{prop1 = "Name2", prop2="application"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name2", prop2="core"},
            new Test{prop1 = "Name2", prop2="project"}
        };
```

**The expected output is like this**

Name1          project

Name1          project235

Name1          application

Name1          application21

Name1          application33331

Name1          core1

Name1          core222

Name2          project

Name2          application

Name2          core

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: And you've tried...(?)

Comment: It's not clear if the "prop2" values of "your choice" have to be flexible. The current values seem like they could be sorted based on just prop1, then by prop2

Comment: @TGH it's very clear that he wants to order by prop1 first then by prop2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. sorry the output look very straight forward But I want flexibility in prop2. For example I would like to display first "project" then "Appllication" and then "Core"

Comment: @Miranchowdhery if so, looks like that you want to order the `prop2` by descending if `prop1 = Name1`, otherwise the `prop2` will be ordered by ascending. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @KingKing - Sorry my bad...I have updated my question and also the expected output. prop2 sorting shouldn't be either asc or dsc. it should be random. For example "project", "application", "core".

Comment: @Miranchowdhery if so, the `prop2` in fact is not sorted, we don't have any kind of sort called `random sort`. See my updated answer if it is what you want.

Comment: @KingKing - prop2 is not random sort. my customer says I want prop2 in this order. Tomorrow customer may change the mind and can give a request for other specific order (prop2 can contain 20 different and unique values). Please see the Damith's reply. It works perfect so far and You can display any order you like to...

Comment: @Miranchowdhery I've just understood what you want and just edited my answer, please see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
tests = tests.OrderBy(x=>x.prop1)
.ThenBy(x => x.prop2 == null)
.ThenBy(x=>!x.prop2.Contains("project"))
.ThenBy(x=>!x.prop2.Contains("core"))
.ThenBy(x=>!x.prop2.Contains("application"))
.ThenBy(x=>x.prop2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! This solved the problem. I changed the query little bit and it worked

Comment: tests = tests.OrderBy(x => x.prop1)
            .ThenBy(x => !x.prop2.Contains("project"))
            .ThenBy(x => !x.prop2.Contains("core"))
            .ThenBy(x => !x.prop2.Contains("application"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.prop2).ToList();

Comment: Thanks again. Now if I have any prop2=null in the list then I want to show that list item at last. How do I do that? I have changed the code like this and NULL is displayed at the beginning. tests = tests.OrderBy(x => x.prop1)
            .ThenBy(x => x.prop2 != null && !x.prop2.Contains("project"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.prop2 != null && !x.prop2.Contains("core"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.prop2 != null && !x.prop2.Contains("application"))
            .ThenBy(x => x.prop2).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = tests.GroupBy(x=>x.prop1)
                   .SelectMany(g=>g.GroupBy(x=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.prop2) ? 1
                                               x.prop2.StartsWith("project") ? 2 :
                                               x.prop2.StartsWith("application") ? 3 : 4)
                                   .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
                                   .Select(a=>a.OrderBy(x=>x.prop2)));
```

Comment: Its not compiling..Am I missing any assembly? its complaining with StartsWith extention method